# Mule Configuration Flow SAXParseException

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I have this MuleSoft Configuration Flow and I am getting the following error, I think maybe I am missing an include or something.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.8.1:process-classes (default-process-classes) on project account-collateral-api: Execution default-process-classes of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.8.1:process-classes failed: There was '1' error while parsing the given file 'account-collateral-api-acctcollaterals-acctcollateralrelkeys-acctcollateralrelid-get.xml'.
[ERROR] Full list:
[ERROR] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 31; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":uri-params}'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":response-validator}' is expected.
```

This is the configuration flow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd       
                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd       
                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">

    <flow
        name="get:\acctCollaterals\acctCollateralRelKeys\(acctCollateralRelId):application\json:account-collateral-api-config">
        <logger level="INFO" message="Request: #[payload]" />
        <logger level="INFO" message="Service Request: #[payload]" />
        <http:request
            config-ref="http-account-collateral-api-request" method="GET"
            path="acctCollaterals\acctCollateralRelKeys\(acctCollateralRelId)">
            <http:headers><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
"content-type" : "application/json"
}]]]></http:headers>
            <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
"limit" : attributes.queryParams.'limit',
"cursor" : attributes.queryParams.'cursor'
}]]]></http:query-params>
            <http:uri-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
"acctCollateralRelId" : attributes.uriParams.'acctCollateralRelId'
}]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
        <logger level="INFO" message="Service Response: #[payload]" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload
                    resource="mappings/responses/acctcollaterals-acctcollateralrelkeys-acctcollateralrelid-responses-mapping.dwl" />
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" message="Response: #[payload]" />
        <error-handler ref="private-errorhandler" />
    </flow>

</mule>
```

It has the following dependencies included in the maven pom.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tracing-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-secure-configuration-property-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.13</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.13</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.weave</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertions</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can't seem to see the error, I am sure I am just looking at it too long!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please verify if your dwl files are not empty?

Comment: uri parameters should be enclosed with curly brackets - ie. `{}` - instead of parenthesis i.e. `()`

Comment: The dw is fine, and the error seems to be around the uri param, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Error seems to indicate the issue is with this part of the code, but shows fine on the message flow.   </http:query-params>
   <http:uri-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
"acctCollateralRelId" : attributes.uriParams.'acctCollateralRelId'
}]]]></http:uri-params>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  So apparently the XML for the HTTP Request has a order.  First headers, then uri params, then query params.  If they are out of order the app fails to compile.